# Render a different template for a user who is not logged in while preserving the URL

Tags: meteor, iron-router

If a user is not logged in, I want to render a `SignIn` template for him while preserving the URL of the page. When he does log-in, then I want to continue rendering of the URL he original tried to visit.

The following bit of CoffeeScript shows the intent of what I am trying to accomplish. A version close to this worked until recently, until I updated to Meteor 0.8:

```coffeescript
# If the user is not signed in, render the signin template instead of the
# actual page. However, keep the URL the same.

mustBeSignedIn = (pause) ->
    if not Meteor.user()?
        # How to render a different template from the intended one here?
        ### vvv ----
        @render('masterLayout'
            yieldTemplates:
                signIn:
                    to: 'content'
        )
        pause()

Router.onBeforeAction(mustBeSignedIn, {
    except: [ 'signIn' ]
})
```

My `layoutTemplate` contains a `yield` region with the name `"content"`:

```
<template name="masterLayout">
  <div id="container-content">
     {{> yield region="content"}}
  </div>
</template>
```

The `signingIn` and `signIn` templates are defined and other paths render properly when I go to them directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for `yield`-ing to templates is described in the [DOCS.md file](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/dev/DOCS.md#custom-rendering):

> You can render manually by calling the render function. There are
>   three ways to call the render method:
>
> - `this.render()`: Render all of the templates for the Route or RouteController. This renders the main template into the main yield region, and all of the yieldTemplates into their associated `{{> yield region='name'}}` regions.
> - `this.render('templateName')`: Render the template named 'templateName' into the main yield `{{> yield}}`.
> - `this.render('templateName', {to: 'region'})`: Render the template named 'templateName' into the region named 'region' `{{> yield
>     region='region'}}`.

The third point answers the question about how to render a template *to* a named region.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to return the result of the render function.

```
mustBeSignedIn = (pause) ->
    if not Meteor.user()?

        return @render('masterLayout'
            yieldTemplates:
                signIn:
                    to: 'content'
        )
```

Also its good practice to favor `Meteor.userId()` over `Meteor.user()` since userId() is only reactive if the userId changes where as user() will cause your onBeforeAction to be run any time there is a change to the current users record.

Comment: That looks like a pre-emptive return to me, which will not execute the `pause()` function at all. Thanks about the comment about `Meteor.user()` v/s `Meteor.userId()`. :)

Comment: You're right.. you can actually remove the pause all together. I'll edit to reflect.